# Depend gradle build on google maps only

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle, build.gradle

My project depends on maps. So I have `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.0.0'` in my `build.gradle` file. But gradle downloads all the play services, including fitness, games, wallet, etc. How to depend just on map and it's dependencies, but not the whole play-services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a problem. The issue was that gradle was configured to work in offline and for unknown reason it was adding all the play-services into the project (perhaps, because full play-services was the only downloaded dependency, that contained play-services-maps).
Allowing gradle to work online and doing gradle sync — and viola, now only `play-services-base` and `play-services-maps` are dependencies.